# Which conjunction has to be used for contrasting the sentences? Details provided in description

Tags: conjunctions, subordinate-clauses

When I was speaking to an automobile enthusiast, I came across a situation where I couldn't express what I had in my mind about the kick-starter bikes.

I want to know the better conjunction to connect two clauses. The second clause has to be contrasted more than the first clause.

**Clause 1:** ***Sometimes the Kickback even from bikes with lower displacement could be more painful while kick-starting.***

**Clause 2:** ***You could think how tremendously painful it could be when the bikes with higher displacements kickback while kick-starting.***

**Kickback means, a sudden forceful recoil of a kick lever used for kick-starting.**

Which conjunction can be used to convey increase of contrast?

Comment: Outside of Indian English, "doubt" doesn't mean "question". One "doubts" (verb) something when one is unsure of its validity.

Comment: This is not really a contrast (and you can't show *more* contrast in one half of a thing, only the contrast between them). This is similar to a sentence like "All aircraft carriers are huge, **so** you can imagine how big the new Mega Aircraft carrier is." A contrast would be "Most aircraft carriers are huge, **but** the new mini-aircraft carrier is actually quite a bit smaller."

Comment: Cross-posting is not cool; I voted to re-open here, and now I feel like I have been played.

Comment: The kickback from starting even a small bike can be very painful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a non-bikie, but suggest the following modification of @Cascabel, which I think is an improvement as it seems to me more natural spoken English.

> “The kick-back from lower displacement bikes *can be painful enough*,
> **so** imagine how it feels on a bike with a higher displacement”

Comment: I was explaining why I thought my modification was better, when the post was magically transported here and my edit magically lost. If you really want to know I will repeat it, but not now.

Answer (score 3):

"***Although*** the kick-back from lower displacement bikes can be quite painful, imagine how it feels on a bike  with a higher displacement"

This usage of the conjunction  "although' subordinates the first clause  for the last.

or other suggestions...

***As*** painful ***as*** kickback from higher-displacment bikes can be, you ***would*** think the lower-displacement bikes would be less so.

or...

You might think that the kickback from a high-displacement bike would be painful, ***but*** a lower-displacement could be more painful.

***Even though*** the kickback from a higher displacement can be painful, it  can be more painful on a lower-displacment.

---

I am a bikie with 30+ years of experience on 'big' and street/off-road bikes.

That includes Yamaha, Honda, and others, from 200 to 750 cc.

As far as I know, kick-back is only an issue if there is a defect in the  release, or the rider is not heavy enough to push the bike through a full cycle and spark. I think on Harleys it requires something like 150 pounds of pressure, but smaller 2-cycles need less than 90 pounds.

All of that said, I am relying on my personal knowledge to re-word the sentence.

Comment: or forgot to retard the ignition... if it sparks before reaching TDC... whoops. I like the phrasing though.

Comment: @WeatherVane I used to ride a VF750F V4: imagine the problems with dwell on a bike with 4 carbs and 4 cylinders.  I was almost glad when I finally 'crashed and trashed' it.

Comment: I was remembering a [Panther 600](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panther_Model_100) single with hand controls for valve lifter, mixture and timing. Apparently it could hurl you backwards if you got it wrong, but that never happened to me. Mine was probably one of the  last they made.

Comment: @Cascabel Thanks for all your suggestions. It helped me a lot.